Verification that Azure Yaml build pipeline Terraform graph command is correct
Can anyone verify this build step is correct Specifically the customCommand attribute?
- task: TerraformTaskV4@4   displayName: 'Generate Terraform Graph'   inputs:   provider: 'azurerm'   workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.ARTIFACT_NAME }}/${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT }}'   command: 'custom'   customCommand: 'graph -type=plan | dot -Tpng > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/graph.png'   environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.SERVICE_ARM_NAME }}  
I am not skilled in Terraform but I am looking to output a graph providing a visual representation of the Terraform script.

I tried your task, it cannot recognize the command in TerraformTaskV4@4 task, screenshot below:

Instead, you can use AzureCLI@2 with the command directly, it works on my side. I published the png file for checking.
pool:
  vmImage: Ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: SERVICE_ARM_NAME 
    default: ARMConn2

steps:
- task: TerraformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    terraformVersion: 'latest'

- script: |
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y graphviz
  displayName: 'Install Graphviz'       # install the tool to use `dot` in command below

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn2'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      terraform init
      terraform graph -type=plan | dot -Tpng > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/graph.png
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  # i used default working directory for testing

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/graph.png'
    artifact: 'test'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'



PS: In your script, $(Pipeline.Workspace) is predefined variables which points to /home/vsts/work/1, however the working directory is /home/vsts/work/1/s which has /s at the end. Please consider to use $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) if needed.
